# How to send an email with a string list after loop validation

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm new to the forum. I have a little problem with a vba macro in excel. Probably it's not so difficult for you, but I'm totally new on vba. I have two columns: column "A" with a choice (es. "yes" or "no") and column "B" with a string. I want to send an email with the "B" string list with all the strings (line-by-line) that have "yes" value in "A".

```
Sub Alert()
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
On Error Resume Next
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim list As Object
Dim element As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While Trim(Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value) = ""
On Error GoTo alertmail
For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
 If cell.Value = "yes" Then
  element = Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    list.Add element
 End If
Next cell
Loop

alertmail:
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
            .To = "test@abc.com"
            .Subject = "Alert"
            .Body = "Your yes list is" & vbNewLine & PrintArray
            .Display
End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing

Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Until now, my best result was to send a set of different mail with only one "B" string for every "yes" "A" value  (i.e. if I have 3 "yes" value I obtain 3 mails with the correct "B" string for each).

Comment: Remove on `On Error Resume Next` and fix your errors. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur. I recommend to install a proper error handling in this procedure: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Sub Alert()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim list As String
    Dim element As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While Trim(Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value) = ""
    On Error GoTo alertmail
    For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value = "yes" Then
            element = Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
            list = list & vbNewLine & element
        End If
    Next cell
    Loop

alertmail:
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
                .To = "to@xyz.com"
                .Subject = "Alert"
                .Body = "Your yes list is" & vbNewLine & list
                .Display
    End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing

    Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have a second question about the macro. If my "yes" value was write as string in "A" the macro works perfectly, but if "yes" value was obtain from the function in cell "A" (es. A1=IF(C1=1;"yes";"no")), with column "C" conditions choice it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem replace `For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` with `For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells`